# eval: $? vs ${PIPESTATUS[@]} (bash)

Tags: bash, eval

In bash 5.0, I wish to capture the `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` of a piped command that is executed via `eval`. However, `eval` appears to mask `${PIPESTATUS[@]}`, but doesn't mask `$?` which is the equivalent to `${PIPESTATUS[-1]}`. Is there a way to extract `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` from the results of `eval`? Appending something to the commandstring below like `&& array=( ${PIPESTATUS[@]} ) && export array` does not appear to work.

Am I correct in assuming from this that `$?` is not simply `${PIPESTATUS[-1]}`?

My sample code (ran as root):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#without eval, ${PIPESTATUS[@]} has two entries as it should.
apt-get install -y java-17-openjdk-amd64 2>&1 | tee -a ~/log 
commandsPipestatus=( ${PIPESTATUS[@]} )
for status in ${commandsPipestatus[@]}; do
    echo $status
done

echo ""
echo ""

#with eval, ${PIPESTATUS[@]} has one entry and is equal to $?
commandstring="apt-get install -y java-17-openjdk-amd64 2>&1 | tee -a ~/log"
eval "$commandstring"
commandsPipestatus=( ${PIPESTATUS[@]} )
for status in ${commandsPipestatus[@]}; do
    echo $status
done
```

EDIT: Fixed a small technical correction in my original statement about PIPESTATUS. Also, based on the answers below, here are some clarifications:

- I'm using `eval` because I'm building command strings programmatically and some of them may contain `bash -c`... which run the command as different users.
- I looked at setting `pipefail` and that may work sometimes though not always because sometimes I need to know the status of multiple steps in the pipe. If I could set `set -o pipefail` and then unset it after that could work, but I'm not seeing how to unset `pipefail` and I can't simply exit the subshell and then continue in a new one where `pipefail` is not been set. How do I unset a shell option such as `pipefail`?
- Is my above understanding of how to export an array that contains `PIPESTATUS` incorrect? How can I simply export `PIPESTATUS` from the `eval` subshell?

EDIT 2: Thanks to the excellent answer marked below, my final decision was for the case where I am dynamically assembling command strings that include redirection (which is why I need eval), I would use `set -o pipefail` and then after execution do `set +o pipefail`.

I'm also re-researching best practices for executing dynamically built commands, as I have several years more bash experience since the last time I did. My use cases for `eval` are:

1. Commands may contain `bash -c`, so I can't use `bash -c` to execute them
2. May contain redirection, such as `>> log`
3. The dynamical commands may also have arguments added to them for debugging purposes

As far as I can tell, I may be able to do things differently for 1, and for 3 I should be using things like `set -x [command]` and `trap` instead. I have yet to find a solution for 2.

Comment: I'd start by questioning why you even need `eval`

Comment: Don't put commands into variables. Variables are for data, functions are for code

Comment: @muru thanks for your question, I've clarified in my post.

Comment: @ChrisDavies, I've clarified in my post why this is required.

Comment: "_I'm using eval because I'm building command strings programmatically_" - that is not a reason to use `eval`. There are many examples on this site showing how to do this properly - and certainly without `eval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$?` contains the status of rightmost component of the last command that was run (or the rightmost failing component, if `pipefail` is set), though possibly modified by the `!` prefix keyword.

The elements of `$PIPESTATUS` are the exit statuses of each component of the previous pipeline, with `!` having no effect on the values.

After `(exit 1) | (exit 2) | (exit 3)`, `$PIPESTATUS` will be (1 2 3) and `$?` will be 3. After `! (exit 1) | (exit 2) | (exit 3)`, `$PIPESTATUS` will be the same, but `$?` will be 0, same as `$(( ! 3 ))`.

`false` or `(exit 1)` is still a pipeline with one component, in the first case a simple command, in the second a subshell, so you get `PIPESTATUS=(1)` and `$?` = 1.

That's the same in `eval 'any shell code'` which is just one simple command.

After `eval 'A | B' | C`, `$PIPESTATUS` will contain the exit status of `eval` (which will be that of the last command it runs: `B`) and that of `C`. Same in `(A | B) | C` by the way.

You could do:

```
eval '
  A | B
  saved_STATUS=$? saved_PIPESTATUS=( "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" )
'
```

To preserve the status of the pipeline components, as seen by the interpreter invoked by `eval`, so in your case:

```
preserve_status='
  saved_STATUS=$? saved_PIPESTATUS=( "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" )
'
eval "$commandstring $preserve_status"
commandsPipestatus=( "${saved_PIPESTATUS[@]}" )
for status in "${commandsPipestatus[@]}"; do
    echo "$status"
done
```

However here, it seems to me you'd rather want:

```
install_java() (
  set -o pipefail
  apt-get install -y java-17-openjdk-amd64 2>&1 | tee -a ~/log
)
```

That is:

- store code in function, not variables
- use the `pipefail` option so that that function returns failure if either `apt-get` or `tee` fail. Note that the body of the function is a subshell instead of the more common *command group* command (`{ ...; }`) which means that option is only set locally. With recent versions of `bash`, you can also use `local -; set -o pipefail` for the option to be set locally in the function without the need for a subshell.

Note however that both the normal output and the errors of `apt-get` will be sent to stdout.

If using `zsh`, you could do:

```
exec {log}>> ~/log # at the beginning of the script for instance.
apt-get install -y java-17-openjdk-amd64 >&1 >&$log 2>&2 2>&$log
```

To send both the stdout of stderr of `apt-get` to the log and to their respective original destination. The `tee`ing is done internally, and the exit status of `apt-get` is preserved.

And maybe make a helper function for that such as:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
die() { print -ru2 -C1 -- "$@"; exit 1; }
exec {log}>> ~/log
with_log() { "$@" >&1 >&$log 2>&2 2>&$log; }

with_log apt-get ... || die "Aborting..."
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using eval because I'm programmatically building command strings and those strings may contain bash -c ... because they're run as different users. Regarding pipefail, I can't necessarily use it every time because sometimes the command string can contain pipes that I need to know the exit codes of different parts of the pipe. Pipefail could work in some cases, though I'm not seeing how to unset pipefail. If I could set pipefail for a specific command and then unset it directly after, that could work. However my main question is, how do I get PIPESTATUS from eval?

Comment: @jitter, you unset `pipefail` with `set +o pipefail`, but see how that body of that function in the example I gave is a subshell instead of being a command group, so that option only applies in there and not to the rest of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Using a function instead of `eval` is probably the better solution.

So you could do something like this, allowing the install of multiple packages if required:

```
install() {
  apt-get install -y "${1}" 2>&1 | tee -a ~/log
}
packages=("java-17-openjdk-amd64")
for pkg in "${packages[@]}" ; do
  install pkg
  # replace below with actions based on status
  printf "%s\n" "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
done
```

`set -o pipefail` is a way to bubble up the error from the `apt-get` command without having to inspect all of `PIPESTATUS`, but things could get a little murky if, say, your `tee` can't write to its log.

EDIT: based on additional info

I surmising the problem you are having with `eval` is because it is running your command in a subshell (or at least behaving in a similar manner). It feels like you are only ever going to get a single exit code (happy to be wrong on that assumption).

You could print the pipe status within the command, but it will be tricky to get at it.

This monstrosity is one way you could approach it, but it's quite convoluted and some bespokeness is required around the text processing as regards your command, and still only able to get one exit code out at the end

```
# just some stuff to print some text and exit with a non zero
# before the next pipeline step masks the exit code

foo='bash -c "echo hello;false" | tee log;echo PIPE ${PIPESTATUS[@]}'
# awk grabs the line with the pipe status text, pulls one of
# the exit codes from it and exits with it, otherwise prints
# the output as seen

eval "$foo" | awk '
  {if ($1=="PIPE"){print "just showing you I saw all the codes "$0;exit $2}; print $0}'
echo $?
```

I feel like there is something that could be done to feed the `awk` output into `readarray` to capture the different pipe statuses, but it's going to be pretty messy (on top of already messy).

When something gets this ugly, you have to start to wonder if the whole approach is wrong.

Perhaps if you elaborate more on your requirements a different way to go about it may present itself.

Comment: The install command is just a simple example. I am using eval because I'm programmatically building command strings and those strings may contain bash -c ... because they're run as different users. I can't necessarily use pipefail every time because the command string can contain pipes that I need to know the exit codes of different parts of the pipe. Pipefail could work in some cases, though I'm not seeing how to unset pipefail. Maybe set pipefail and then unset it directly after? In any case, how do I get PIPESTATUS from eval? Is my understanding of exporting an array incorrect?

Comment: `set +o pipefail` will disable pipefail